# Get Persian texts from database with PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have problem get data from database. Persian words appear as question marks like `???????`. How can I avoid this?

Here is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "somevalue", "somevalue", "somevalue");
$output = array();
$query  = "SELECT * FROM af_home ORDER BY home_id DESC LIMIT 50";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: Please don't share your DB credentials on public platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that the `af_home` column charset is UTF-8 from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can convert database UTF-8:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database CHARACTER SET utf8;
-- for each table:
ALTER TABLE some_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

and make sure that the table is UTF8:

```
SET CHARACTER SET, SET NAMES, SET COLLATION_CONNECTION
```